# Como buscar um único campo de 3 tabelas com JOIN utilizando Respect\Relational?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou começando a utilizar o framework `Respect\Relational` e estava tentando buscar apenas os nomes dos modelos de carta que pertencem a linha de negócio de id 1, mas todas as formas que tentei sempre retorna todas as colunas. Qual seria a forma correta de fazer isto utilizando o framework `Respect\Relational`?

Esta é a imagem da parte do banco necessária:

> [image: Tabelas necessárias para a consulta]

Estas foram algumas tentativas e que também não deram certo:

```
$this->mapper->letterTemplatesNames = Filtered::by('name')->letter_templates();

$this->mapper->hiddenLetterTemplatesBusinessLines = 
      Filtered::letter_templates_business_lines();

$response = $this->mapper->letter_templates
      ->letter_templates_business_lines
      ->business_lines[(int) $value]
      ->fetchAll(Sql::orderBy('letter_templates.name')
      ->asc()
      ->limit($limit));

$response = $this->mapper->letter_templates
      ->letter_templates_business_lines(
          array('business_lines_id' => (int) $value))
      ->fetchAll(Sql::orderBy('letter_templates.name')
      ->asc()
      ->limit($limit));

$response = $this->mapper->letterTemplatesNames
      ->letter_templates_business_lines
      ->business_lines[(int) $value]
      ->fetchAll(Sql::orderBy('letter_templates.name')
      ->asc()
      ->limit($limit));

$response = $this->mapper
      ->hiddenLetterTemplatesBusinessLines(
        array('business_lines_id' => (int) $value))
      ->letterTemplatesNames
      ->fetchAll(Sql::orderBy('letter_templates.name')
      ->asc()
      ->limit($limit));
```

Comment: Coloque também as tentativas, os códigos!

Comment: Pronto, havia me esquecido. Obrigado!

Comment: o melhor é não trabalhar com esse `Wrapper` não considero um `MicroOrm` (bom essa é minha opinião), tem que melhorar muito, principalmente nos `Joins` e `Select`, use um `ActiveRecords` ou `Eloquent` (é um ORM do `Laravel` mas que funciona fora do também). Só lembrando que tentei fazer, mas, na hora de escolhar os itens do `Select` eu não achei como!

Comment: Entendi, estarei olhando os itens que citou.
Em relação a escolher os itens do `Select` uma opção é fazer através do     Filtered::by()

Comment: *Errata:
Entendi, estarei olhando os itens que citou.
Em relação a escolha dos itens do `Select` uma opção é fazer através do `Filtered::by()` que pode ser utilizado através de `use Respect\Data\Collections\Filtered;`, nos códigos que postei tem um exemplo desta utilização.